# Add custom field in review form

Tags: magento-1.9, database, review

I want to add a custom field to the review form in Magento.
I have tried this but the data is not saved, it shows the field.

app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Review\Edit\Form.php

```
$fieldset->addField('email', 'text', array( // New field 1
'label' => Mage::helper('review')->__('Email'),
'required' => true,
'name' => 'email'
));
```

After

```
$fieldset->addField('nickname', 'text', array(
'label' => Mage::helper('review')->__('Nickname'),
'required' => true,
'name' => 'nickname'
));
```

app\design\frontend\theme\theme\template\review\form.phtml

```
        <li class="formlistreview">
            <label for="email_field" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('E-mail') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email_field" class="input-text required-entry" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($data->getEmail()) ?>" />
            </div>
        </li>
```

app\code\core\Mage\Review\Model\Resource\Review.php

```
protected function _afterSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
{
$detail = array(
'title' => $object->getTitle(),
'detail' => $object->getDetail(),
'nickname' => $object->getNickname(),
'email' => $object->getEmail(), // New field 1
);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `$this` instead of `$object`

```
protected function _afterSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
{
$detail = array(
'title' => $this->getTitle(),
'detail' => $this->getDetail(),
'nickname' => $this->getNickname(),
'email' => $this->getEmail(), // New field 1
);
```

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara dear check the error log what error their check for exception and etc what i can do from only url?

Comment: The default code with `$object` worked for me, even for my custom field. I did however have to add the custom field as column to `review_detail` in my database.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do is add a column `email` in `review_detail` table. Then this issue would be resolved.

It's too old post, but it might help someone.
So, i just figured out the solution.